# On the proof that $(\Bbb{Q}\otimes A)\cap (\Bbb{Z}_p\otimes A)=\Bbb{Z}_{(p)}\otimes A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, abelian-groups, p-adic-number-theory

Let, for $p$ prime integer, $\Bbb{Q},\Bbb{Z}_{(p)},\Bbb{Z}_p, \Bbb{Q}_p$ be the field of rationals, the ring of rationals whose denominator is prime to $p$, the ring of $p$-adic integers and the field of $p$-adic numbers, respectively.

Recall that an abelian group is a $\Bbb{Z}$-module and that such a group is torsion-free iff every nonzero element has infinite order.

As far as I understand, $\Bbb{Z}$-linear independence and $\Bbb{Q}$-linear independence are the same, for torsion-free $A$.

The following fact holds for every prime integer $p$ and every torsion-free abelian group $A$:
$$(\Bbb{Q}\otimes A)\cap (\Bbb{Z}_p\otimes A)=\Bbb{Z}_{(p)}\otimes A$$

My questions are about the proof of this fact.

**Proof.**
Let $x \in \Bbb{Z}_p\otimes A$, so that we can write down $x=\sum_{i=1}^n\pi_ia_i$ where $\pi_i\in\Bbb{Z}_p$ and $a_i\in A$.
Wlog we may assume $a_1,\dots,a_k$ $\Bbb{Z}$-linearly independent and $\pi_{k+1},\dots,\pi_n$ rational integers (I got this).

If $x\in \Bbb{Q}\otimes A$, then $x$ depends on a maximal $\Bbb{Z}$-linearly independent system $\{a_1,\dots,a_k,a'_{k+1},\dots\}$ of $A$, say
$$x=\sum_{i=1}^km_ia_i+\sum_{i=k+1}^rm_ia'_i$$
for rational numbers $m_i$.

> (1) A maximal independent system of $A$ becomes, after identifying $1\otimes a$ with $a$, a maximal independent system in the $\Bbb{Q}_p$-module $\Bbb{Q}_p\otimes A$,

then

> (2) there is essentially only one dependence relation for $x$.

Thus

> (3) $\pi_1,\dots,\pi_n$ must be rationals

and

> (4) $x\in \Bbb{Q}_p\otimes A$.

This proves $(\Bbb{Q}\otimes A)\cap (\Bbb{Z}_p\otimes A)\le \Bbb{Q}_p\otimes A$. QED

I was not able to prove statements (1),(2),(3),(4).
May you help me, please?

Comment: Here’s a high level reason for the statement:

 1. Torsion-free abelian groups $A$ are flat.
 2. In $ℚ_p$, $ℤ_{(p)} = ℤ_p ∩ ℚ$.
 3. By flatness, intersections are preserved after tensoring with $A$.

Comment: @k.stm OK. After some googling, I got 2. and 3. But I don't see how 1. should help.

Comment: Since $A$ is torsion-free, $A$ is flat by (1), which you need to apply (3).

Comment: I apologize, my question was bad written. I don't understand how flatness relates to linear independence

Comment: Flatness of $A$ doesn’t, but flatness of $ℚ_p$ over $ℤ$ does: So let $R → S$ be a ring extension and $A$ be an $R$-module. Consider maps $R^n → A$ and their scalar extensions $S^n → S \otimes_R A$. If $R → S$ is flat, you get “*$R^n → A$ is injective $\implies$ $S^n → S\otimes A$ is injective*”. If $R → S$ is injective (as implied with ring extensions), you get the other direction. Just consider the diagram
\begin{array}{ccccc}
0 &→ & R^n &→& A \\
 & & ↓ & & ↓ \\
0 & → & S\otimes_R R^n & → & S \otimes_R A.
\end{array}